# Collimating and homogenizing a divergent tunable-spectrum light source

Tags: optics, visible-light

I have a light source (Xenon lamp) which has the possibility to be tuned over spectral range of 390 - 740 nm with 1 nm spectral accuracy . Bandwidth at each wavelength is about 20 nm .
Output intensity is 350 mW full spectrum at output of 5 mm liquid light guide (1.5mW/nm typical , 1.8 mW/nm peak)
Output light is divergent and to some extent not coherent.
What I'm looking for actually is to illuminate a few square cm (1-3) of surface with a well **collimated** and **homogenous** light coming from mentioned light source.(power is not of importance since several micro Watts would be sufficient)
Which setup can I utilize with lab instruments like pinholes , lenses and ...?
Which task should be done 1st (collimation or homogenization)(Or may be it can be done simoltanously)?
Do you have any suggestion what is the best way to remain in good collimation and homogeneity with proposed setup when we sweep over the spectrum ?
(Both experimental as well as theoretical approaches are of interest)